# Connecting Database Server to Cloned Production Version

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I'm making my first ASP.net application in C# using Visual Studio, and I have a working development version.  After creating a separate production database, I used Windows Explorer to copy the entire development project folder.  The production folder name and the .sln file name were both changed in the production version.

Now, though, the production `.edmx` file's Model Browser shows nothing under Stored Procedures/Functions, even though the Complex Types and Function Imports still exist, and no stored procedures can be found to import or update.  This is after the `Web.config` connection strings have been pointed to the production database server, including the id and password, and the data connections have been added and tested successfully through the Server Explorer.  There's also an SQLException `Login failed for user 'databaseuser'.` where databaseuser is the id in the Web.config connection strings, whenever the production app is tested.

Does anyone know how to connect the copied production project to the database server?  Many thanks in advance!

**Web.config connection strings:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        connectionString="Server=[production server];Database=UserDatabase;
        User ID=databaseuser;Password=[production password];Trusted_Connection=False;
        Connection Timeout=30;" />
    <add name="WorkDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=[metadata copied from 
        working development version];provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
        provider connection string=&quot;data source=[production server];
        initial catalog=WorkDatabase;integrated security=False;user id=databaseuser;
        password=[production password];multipleactiveresultsets=True;
        application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="UserDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=[metadata copied from 
        working development version];provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
        connection string=&quot;data source=[production server];
        initial catalog=UserDatabase;integrated security=False;user id=databaseuser;
        password=[production password];connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
        App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**EDIT 1**

The Model Browser in the `.edmx` file now shows Stored Procedures.  The "databaseuser" had Read and Write permissions on the WorkDatabase, but didn't have dbo Schema under Securables.

**EDIT 2**

Here's a bit of the Stack Trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'databaseuser'.]
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +347
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +141
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +362
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
```

**EDIT 3**

The stack trace seems to alternate between two different traces.  What does that indicate?

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'databaseuser'.]
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +970
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +802
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +682
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +141
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +362
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
```

**EDIT 4**

The server is being hosted on AWS.  Maybe it's something specific to AWS?

Comment: Do you have any db server firewall rules that prohibits the production db from being accessed from the local machine

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I don't believe there are any firewall issues.

Comment: if you cloned the database and the project there would not be anything to import.. you just change the connection string to point to production or development and you should be good to go.. assuming they are clones

Comment: @JamieD77 - there are no new stored procedures to import, but the stored procedures aren't even showing up in the '.edmx' file.  Plus, there's the SQLException whenever the production version is tested even though Server Explorer says the server is connected.

Comment: There could be no issue with the connection, if it connects in ssms, it should work in VS. BTW, restating VS and clearing the temp asp.net files can be tried. Maybe VS cache issue we noticed in VS2013

Comment: are you looking at the model browser and not seeing them?

Comment: @Saravanan - Restarting VS didn't seem to help, but I haven't deleted temporary files.  Are these the ones to clear: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root?

Comment: @JamieD77 - The Complex Types and Function Imports in the Model seem to show up correctly, but the Stored Procedures in the Model.Store to which they refer are not showing up, even after the 1st attempt asked me to connect to a server, which I did there and in the Server Explorer.

Comment: @Saravanan - I deleted everything in the root subfolder, but the error still occurs.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the exact exception message copied and pasted including a tiny bit of stacktrace? Often, there is extra information after the title of the message that can give us better hints. For instance, if a SQL message number is returned, then we know for a fact that your code is connecting to the instance, and we can rule out network issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked, but here's what apparently cured the problem: I removed the Web.config credentials for "databaseuser" with only read/write access and replaced them with the database admin credentials.  The application tested successfully.  The administrator credentials were then replaced with the original "databaseuser" credentials, and everything works.  It seems like for some reason the application needed the admin to access the connection for the first time, then the read/write user could thenceforth do the same.

Thank you to everyone for the answers.  They're all correct and were being done, but for some reason the program needed the admin to first show it the way.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue where the prod database has more restrictive permissions on the stored procs.  My user could execute them but not 'see' them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't set up the appropriate SQL permissions for the user you trying to log in with for the production database.

Two things are required to "log in" and query a sql server database.

1. A sql login stored in syslogins of the master database: `SELECT * FROM master.sys.syslogins`
2. A sql user on the specific database you want to query created from the login in the master database: `SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.sys.sysusers` (that query might not be 100% accurate in terms of returning the correct 'users', but if you have a user in that database, it will definitely show up in that query)

[MSDN on creating a user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx#Anchor_1)

Based on the error message that you posted, it sounds like the Sql login in the master database does not exist. Using SSMS or Server Explorer, you should be able to expand the "security > logins" folder on you sql instance and see all the logins that exist. If the userId in your connection string does not appear in that list, then you will not be able to connect to the database.

You may also just need to create the user in the database that you want to query. I forget if that error has the same wording for both cases. You should be able to check with SSMS or Server explorer by going to "DatabaseName > Security > Users" to check.

Once the user and login is created, you might get a different error saying something about permissions, or access denied or something. In this case, the *database user* that you have created, does not have the sufficient *role* in that database to query the table. In that case, you need to figure out which role you need to add your user to so that it can query. This can vary from database to database.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The database user is created and assigned read/write public access in both databases that the project queries.  Going off the test server, which I didn't create, the database user is assigned a dbo Schema in Securables for one database, but not the one that manages users.  Could the user need the same Securables setting in the other database?

Comment: The user is created in both databases, but what about the sql login in the master database?

Comment: I believe it's there.  It was created in the Security folder at the server level and assigned to the two necessary databases.  One of the databases can now be accessed, but the users database cannot be.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are getting for each database?

Comment: The database with dbo Schema defined in the Securables can be accessed, so there's no error for each database.  The error for the user database is "Login failed for user 'databaseuser'."

Comment: Just to explicitly confirm: you have one user 'databaseuser', databaseuser is able to successfully query 'WorkDatabase' without error, but you are getting 'Login failed for user 'databaseuser'' on UserDatabase?

Comment: The 'database' user itself can log into SQL Server itself, and from Visual Studio can retrieve the stored procedures from WorkDatabase.  When the login code appears that utilizes UserDatabase, the "Login failed for user 'databaseuser'" error appears.